# ¿Cómo poner inicial de cada palabra de un String en mayúscula en JAVA?

Tags: java

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo colocar las iniciales de cada palabra que se encuentren en un **String** en mayúscula, por ejemplo:

```
String Texto="Hola a todos, bienvenidos.";
```

y que el programa me arroje: 
 Hola A Todos, Bienvenidos.

He visto casos en el que usan `char[]`, pero me gustaría conocer otro método que sea más sencillo.

Comment: Por favor, considera añadir como lo has intentado tu :)

Comment: Te invito a leer esto: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Para que esta pregunta no quede cerrada, necesitas añadir el código que tengas hecho y especificar cual es la duda o el problema dado.

Comment: Bienvenido, ayudanos a crear preguntas de "calidad", en el sitio, agrega lo que has tratado, es importante,revisa por favor [ask], saludos!

Comment: Importante revisar [¿Es legal tener mas de una cuenta en Stack Overflow y pasarse reputación entre ellas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1141/es-legal-tener-mas-de-una-cuenta-en-stack-overflow-y-pasarse-reputaci%c3%b3n-entre-e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hace poco estuve con la misma inquietud que tú, por suerte pude idear una manera diferente de realizar esto, para ello lo que haremos es separar las palabras y trabajar con cada una de ellas por individual, pero para saber con cuantas palabras vamos a trabajar usamos el método `StringTokenizer`

1. Paso: Creamos un objeto del método `StringTokenizer`.

   `StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(Texto);`

La variable de tipo String Texto contiene el texto que se le haya asignado, `String Texto="Hola a todos, bienvenidos.";`

2. Paso: Contamos la cantidad de palabras que tiene la variable que contenga el texto y la guardamos en una variable entera.

   `int CantidadPalabras=st.countTokens();`

> `st.countTokens` permite contar la cantidad de palabras

3. Paso: Creamos un ciclo `for` que corra por cada una de las palabras.
   Esto con el fin de ejecutar la siguiente linea:

   > `st.nextToxen();` Nos permite ver la palabra en la primera posición, cada vez que se ejecute este comando se mostrará la siguiente palabra.

```java
for(int k=0;k<CantidadPalabras;k++){
    String PalabraIndividual =st.nextToken();                                                
    PalabraCompleta+= PalabraIndividual.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+PalabraIndividual.substring(1).toLowerCase()+" ";
}
```

> El `.substring(0,1)` toma el primer carácter del texto que contiene la palabra individual.
>
> El `.toUpperCase()` Pone en mayúscula el carácter tomado.
>
> El `.substring(1)` toma todos los caracteres luego de la primera posición.
>
> El `.toLowerCase()` Pone en minúscula el resto del texto tomado.

El texto final es guardado en la variable de tipo String `PalabraCompleta` que al irse recorriendo el `for` se le añaden las demás palabras con un espaciado de línea al final.

**RESULTADO FINAL:**

```java
StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(Texto);

int CantidadPalabras=st.countTokens();

  for(int k=0;k<CantidadPalabras;k++){

     String PalabraIndividual=st.nextToken();
     PalabraCompleta+= PalabraIndividual.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+PalabraIndividual.substring(1).toLowerCase()+" ";
  }
    System.out.println("Texto final: "+PalabraCompleta);
```

Espero te haya sido de ayuda.

Comment: Excelente, muy bien.

Comment: Es recomendable responder preguntas que sean realizadas en base a el documento [ask], Importante revisar [¿Es legal tener mas de una cuenta en Stack Overflow y pasarse reputación entre ellas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1141/es-legal-tener-mas-de-una-cuenta-en-stack-overflow-y-pasarse-reputaci%c3%b3n-entre-e)

Answer (score 1):

Para poder capitalizar las letras tu puedes usar el método:

> String.substring()

Se usa de la siguiente manera:

```
String str = "Hola a todos, bienvenidos.";

// capitaliza la primera letra
String output = str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);

System.out.println(output);
```

Por si deseas validarlo, podemos escribir una funcion capitalize() que se asegure de que la cadena tenga al menos un carácter antes de usar el método substring ():

```
public static String capitalize(String str) {
    if(str == null || str.isEmpty()) {
        return str;
    }

    return str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hace mucho no programo en java, [pero una simple busqueda en google](https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20string%20to%20words%20array&oq=java%20string%20to%20words%20array&aqs=chrome..69i57.5772j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) para saber como separar palabras de una sentencia me llevo a hacer este script

```java
String s = "a ver si esto funciona. Espero que el peronismo desaparezca de Argentina, por favor.";
String[] words = s.split("\\W+");
String capitalezedSentence = "";
for (String word: words) {
    String capitalizedWord = word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1);
    s = s.replaceAll(word, capitalizedWord);
}

System.out.println(s);
```

No lo probe, pero la idea espero que la entiendas