# Programa que dado un nombre y apellidos, me convierta las iniciales en mayúsculas en Java

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo String methods, y hasta ahora he conseguido aislar las iniciales, pero no consigo que sean mayúsculas. Seguro que es una tontería y me estoy complicando demasiado. Gracias.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Escribe tu nombre y apellidos:");
    String nombreApellidos = sc.nextLine();

    String[] iniciales = nombreApellidos.split(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < nombreApellidos.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(iniciales[i].charAt(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! con mayusculas te referis a transformarlas en mayusculas? algo asi como ToUpper?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo poner inicial de cada palabra de un String en mayúscula en JAVA?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/334500/c%c3%b3mo-poner-inicial-de-cada-palabra-de-un-string-en-may%c3%bascula-en-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para convertir una letra en mayúscula puedes usar el método `toUpperCase` de la clase `String`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Escribe tu nombre y apellidos:");
        String nombreApellidos = sc.nextLine();
        
        //creamos un String en la cual iremos concatenando cada letra leida     
        String iniciales="";         

        for (int i = 0; i < nombreApellidos.length(); i++) {
            //La primera letra es mayúscula
            if(i==0)iniciales=iniciales+nombreApellidos.toUpperCase().charAt(i);
            else
                //Si encontramos un espacio concatenamos a iniciales
                //convertimos mayúscula el caracter después del espacio vacio
                //aumentamos i en 1 para que no nos vuelva a leer el mismo caracter
                if (nombreApellidos.charAt(i) == ' '){ 
                    iniciales=iniciales+nombreApellidos.charAt(i);
                    iniciales=iniciales+nombreApellidos.toUpperCase().charAt(i+1);
                    i++;
                }
                else
                    iniciales=iniciales+nombreApellidos.charAt(i);
        }
        System.out.println("\n Nombres y Apellidos con primera letra en Mayúscula");
        System.out.println(iniciales);
    }
```

Salida

```
Escribe tu nombre y apellidos:
jose luis brañez chavez

 Nombres y Apellidos con primera letra en Mayúscula
Jose Luis Brañez Chavez
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto, es más legible y fácil de entender, dejé algunos comentarios para que comprendas el funcionamiento.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Escribe tu nombre y apellidos:");
String nombreApellidos = sc.nextLine();

nombreApellidos = nombreApellidos.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");// elimina espacios de más y deja solo uno entre cada palabra
String[] iniciales = nombreApellidos.split(" ");
String resultado = "";

for (int i = 0; i < iniciales.length; i++) {//recorre cada palabra separada por espacio

    char inicial = iniciales[i].charAt(0);
    //reemplaza las iniciales por mayusculas y las va almacenando
    resultado  += iniciales[i].replace(String.valueOf(inicial), String.valueOf(Character.toUpperCase(inicial)))+ " ";
}
System.out.println(resultado);//imprime el resultado final
```